# How can i solve this error: java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, syntax-error, java.util.scanner

When I try to test this function:

```
public int getNumber() throws NumberFormatException {
    System.out.println("Введите число:");
    if (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("Ошибка при вводе");
    }
    return scanner.nextInt();
}

@Test
public void wrongFormat() {
    serviceCalc = mock(ServiceCalc.class);
    given(serviceCalc.getNumber()).willReturn(" ");
}
```

I get an error : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " "
How can I test it on wrong format ?

Comment: You should test for the NumberFormatException that should be thrown for `" "`.

Answer (score 0):

scanner.hasNextInt () checks whether there is a number in the console (input stream), if there is not, then as I see, you throw an exception, use this code:

```java
private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public int getNumber() throws RuntimeException {
    System.out.println("Введите число:");

    int input = 0;

    try {

    input = scanner.nextInt;

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Введенное значение не является числом.");
  }
    return input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the Scanner instance already exist for the `getNumber()` method, I assume you passed in the class constructor? If so, then you can write your test like this:

```
@Test
public void wrongFormat() {
    var scanner = new Scanner("testdata");
    var serviceCalc = new ServiceCalc(scanner);
    var thrownException = assertThrows(NumberFormatException.class, serviceCalc::getNumber);
    assertEquals(thrownException.getMessage(), "Ошибка при вводе");
}
```

As you can see, you don't need to mock your `ServiceCalc` class and you shouldn't, because that's the class you want to test, so you need a proper instance of it. This code creates a new Scanner with the String it is supposed to read ([JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String))). Since it is a text string, `hasNextInt()` will return false. This test now verifies that the expected exception is thrown and checks if the exception message is correct.

A positive test case would look like this:

```
@Test
public void correctFormat() {
    var scanner = new Scanner("1234");
    var serviceCalc = new ServiceCalc(scanner);
    var result = serviceCalc.getNumber();
    assertEquals(result, 1234);
}
```

Here the scanner gets a number string to read, so `hasNextInt()` will return true.